# Debugging Wear OS Watch Face

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, wear-os, watch-face-api

I have installed a fresh copy of Android Studio (2021.1.1 Patch 1), downloaded the watch face sample provided on https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin, and am trying to debug it on the emulator (T). However, while I can "run" the face, trying to debug it ends up with the below error message:

```
[AndroidXMetadataFetcher]Timed out creating WatchFaceMetadataClient for WatchFaceId[xxx.watchface,xxx.watchface.AnalogWatchFaceService]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 5000000000 nanoseconds (plus 394200 nanoseconds delay) for androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture@164804c[status=PENDING]
```

At the same time, emulator shows it's waiting for the debugger to attach:
[image]

Any idea how to get Android Studio to behave?